# stale element refernce issue and dom refreshing via explicit/implicit waits

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, explicit, staleelementreferenceexception

I had an issue which I was able to resolve with explicit wait. My curiosity comes, what goes inside selenium webdriver that when I used `implicitly wait` for 300 seconds, it did continue to give stale element reference, but `explicit wait with timeout 77sec` it works without error.
my code is  below

```
for i in range(len(x_indexes)):
    x_indexes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-asin]')))#--here i added explicit wait
    x_data_asin=x_indexes[i].get_attribute('data-asin')#on this line error stale ref was occuring
    if x_data_asin!="":
        
        #clicking to each item for getting iban values ->back page
        a_href_element_of_index=x_block_of_index.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//h2/a')

        a_href_element_of_index.click()
        a_isbn_element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(),"ISBN")]')
        x_isbn_element_parent=a_isbn_element.find_element(By.XPATH,'..')
        print(x_isbn_element_parent.get_attribute('textContent'))
        #driver.back()
        driver.execute_script('window.history.go(-1)')
        print(a_href_element_of_index,'a',sep='-->')
        #driver.implicitly_wait(300)
        --loop ends
```

when i loop each item inside x_indexes I click every anchor element, page directs to another page there i pull out data that i want, then `driver.back` or `driver.execute_script('window.history.go(-1)')` brings me back to the page where iteration continues in same way. I was having stale reference the element was not attached to page, I tried implicitly waiting till 300 after loop was ending line. The result was same error. So when I tried explicitly waiting `wait=WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=77)` the error stopped occuring.
I wonder the logic behind waiting 300 seconds and 77 what lays behind in webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By navigating to another page all collected by Selenium web elements (they are actually references to a physical web elements) become no more valid since the web page is re-built when you open it again.
Now, `driver.implicitly_wait` is setting a timeout for `find_element` and `find_elements` methods only to search for the element(s) according to a given locator. The default `implicitly_wait` is set to `0`. It means that if element is not immediately found on the page, Selenium will throw an exception. By setting `implicitly_wait` to another value it will continue searching for that element until it finds it or the timeout, the first of them.
But this will not help in case you are iterating over **existing** list of previously collected elements `x_indexes` since these references now no more relevant since the web page were re-rendered, as mentioned before.
But if you are using `x_indexes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-asin]')))` this will wait on the main page, were you getting back from the recently opened link, to visibility of these elements, collect the list again, and then you will be able to click on the next element.
Also, normally no need to set `implicitly_wait` or `WebDriverWait` to more than 20-30 seconds.

Comment: `WebDriverWait` does not locate elements in amzn page i think if I set them up below 60. I will try again with 30 sec. But as I remember there was a error, that i was able to get rid of ater setting high timeout num

Comment: This sounds strange... maybe you need to use `caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"`  to reduce page loading time in case there are some JavaScripts there?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found related topic `DesiredCapabilities` I am now looking to it.

Comment: You can open a new question for that and I will try to answer there too :)